# Spark Standalone Mode: Change replication factor of HDFS output

Tags: scala, hdfs, apache-spark

In my `hdfs-site.xml` I configured a replication factor of 1.

However, when writing my result to hdfs:

```
someMap.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://HOST:PORT/out")
```

the results get automatically replicated by a factor of 3, overwriting my own replication factor. To save some space, I would prefer to have a replication factor of 1 for my output as well.

How can spark tell HDFS to use replication factor 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think spark is loading a [default hadoop config](https://github.com/mesos/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/spark/SparkContext.scala#L220) that has replication set to 3. To override it you need to either set an environment variable or system property similar to other spark configurations that you can find [here](http://spark-project.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).

You probably want something like:

```
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.dfs.replication", "1")
```

or in your jvm startup:

```
 -Dspark.hadoop.dfs.replication=1
```

Hopefully something like this *should* work...

Comment: Standard java way of setting properties http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#standard